# Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group $G$. If $a^m$ has order $n$, then $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

> Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group $G$.
>
> If $a^m$ has order $n$, then $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Assume $a^m$ has order $n$ and, $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime.  Then $m$ and $n$ have a common factor, say $q$. So, $m=m'q$ and $n=n'q$. So,

$$(a^m)^{n'}=(a^m)^\frac nq= (a^{mn})^\frac 1q= e^\frac 1q=e$$

So, $(a^m)^\frac nq=(a^m)^n=e$.

Since $a^m$ has order $n$: $e \neq (a^m)^\frac nq = (a^m)^n$. Contradiction.

Comment: Almost correct - you cannot caluclate $(a^{mn})^\frac 1q$. Better write $(a^m)^{n'}=(a^m)^\frac nq= (a^n)^\frac mq= e^\frac mq=e$.

Comment: Why is $\frac 1q$ incorrect?

Comment: Group elements can only have powers of an integer, not a rational number in general. If $g \in G$, then $g^\frac 34$ makes no sense. There is a class of groups, called *divisible* groups where one tries to mimic something like this.

Comment: No need to use any fractions; just observe that $mn' = nm'$, so $(a^m)^{n'} = (a^n)^{m'} = e$ with $n' < n$.

Comment: BTW In general $ord(a^m)=\frac {ord(a)}{gcd(m,ord(a))}$

Comment: For reference, this is 10.G.2 in Pinter.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251207/589

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good, but you can't do $g^{\frac{1}{k}}$ in groups.

---

Let $d=\gcd(m,n)$ and write $m=m'd$, $n=n'd$. Then
$$
(a^m)^{n'}=(a^{m'd})^{n'}=a^{n'dm'}=(a^{n'd})^{m'}=(a^n)^{m'}=e^{m'}=e
$$
Since $n'\le n$ and $a^m$ is assumed to have order $n$, we conclude that $n'=n$, so $d=1$.

Answer (score 0):

10.G.2 from Pinter:

> a ∈ G
>
> ord(a) = n
>
> Prove: If `a^m` has order `n`, then `m` and `n` are relatively prime.
>
> (HINT: Assume `m` and `n` have a common factor `q > 1`, hence we can
>   write `m = m'q` and `n = n'q`. Explain why `(a^m)^n' = e`, and proceed from
>   there.)

(This is an extremely granular step-by-step transformation approach for folks who may be new to this material.)

We are given:

```
a ∈ G                   (1)

ord(a) = n              (2)

ord(a^m) = n            (3)
```

Let's assume `m` and `n` have a common factor `q > 1`. `(4)`

I.e. `gcd(m,n) ≠ 1`.

Thus we can write:

```
m = m' q                                (5)

n = n' q                                (6)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n = n' q        Eq (6).

n' = n/q        Solve for n'.           (7)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
m = m' q        Eq (5).

q = m/m'        Solve for q.            (8)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
n' = n/q        Eq (7).

n' = n/(m/m')   Substitute (8).

n' = nm'/m                              (9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is a long winded way of saying "take `(5)` and `(6)`, isolate `n'` and eliminate `q`.

Let's start with:

```
a^m
```

Raise it to `n'`:

```
(a^m)^n'

(a^m)^(nm'/m)       Substitute (9).

a^(m n m' / m)

a^(n m')            m cancels out.

(a^n)^m'

e^m'                By (2).

e
```

Thus we have:

```
(a^m)^n' = e                        (10)
```

(6) implies that:

```
n' < n                              (11)
```

(10) and (11) together imply that `n` is not the lowest number such that `(a^m)^n = e`.
This contradicts (3).

So our assumption (4) is false.

Comment: It would be much better if you used MathJax.

Comment: @erdoswiles Thanks for the comment. I write up most of my solutions in plain text (Emacs with org-mode). I prefer that over LaTeX. The markup is much more lightweight that way. I understand that this is not popular. That's OK.