# Prove the order of $\omega^k$ is equal to $n/(n,k)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that in $\mathbb{C}$, $ord(\omega^k)=n/(n,k)$.

---

Note that $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$, $ord(\omega)=n$. So if $(\omega^k)^m=1$, then $n|km$, which implies $n|m$. So is it possible to conclude that $ord(\omega^k)=n$ if and only if $(k,n)=1$?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* More generally, $\langle \omega^k \rangle = \langle \omega^d \rangle$ for $d=\gcd(n,k)$.

One inclusion is obvious. The other follows from [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Once this is proved, we have $ord(\omega^k)=ord(\omega^d)=\dfrac{n}{d}=\dfrac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$

All this holds in every group, not just $\mathbb C^\times$.

Comment: Thank you for the general result!